# Initial Process Covariance in 1-D Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters, covariance

Having a bit of confusion about what the initial process covariance (P) should be. Assume a 1-D tracking problem where I am measuring the distance/position of a static object. Would P not just be process error (R) in this case?

// EDIT:

Based on Tim's provided info, my thinking is that the accuracy of my measurement system would basically be this initial uncertainty. For example, if I know the object should be a distance 1 meter away but my measuring system, say a tape measure, is good to only 1cm, then the values within the P matrix should be the square of this uncertainty, or in this case just 1. But, to keep units and magnitude consistent throughout the entire Kalman filter setup using meters (1cm -> 0.01m), this would be a P of 0.0001 then?

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is an expression of your initial uncertainty in the position.  If you start out knowing $x$ *exactly*, then $P = 0$.  If you start out with *no clue* of where $x$ is then, in theory, $P = \infty$, although the math gets harder.

The process error expresses how much you expect $x$ to change at each timestep because of stuff happening.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That helps a lot. Would the accuracy of my measurement system basically be the initial uncertainty? For example, if I know the object should be a distance 1 meter away but my measuring system, say a tape measure, is good to only ± 1cm. Looking at some examples online, the values within the P matrix should be the square of this uncertainty, or in this just 1. But, to keep units and magnitude consistent throughout the entire Kalman filter setup using meters, this would be a P of 0.0001 then?

Comment: OK, Stackexchange is not your usual forum.  They want a closed-form question, with closed-form answers, and they don't want the _real_ question and answer to be buried in the comments.  They _do_ want you to _edit your question_ or start a new one.  In this case, I think this further query is closely related to the rest of your question, so please edit your question -- I or someone else will see when you've done that, and you'll get a more complete answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, question has been updated.

Comment: This is not accurate. The estimation noise is a function of the measurement noise and the process noise. The Kalman filter, in contrast to the LS, assumes the model is stochastic. Hence, even if you have a perfect measurement at a single point of time, it doesn't meant your estimation covariance is 0.

Comment: I didn't say that $x$ was _measured_ perfectly, I said it was _known_ perfectly, by however means.  This fits just fine within the Kalman framework: it just expresses a system where you start out with perfect knowledge of $x$ and then see your knowledge of $x$ degrade over time as it is moved by unknown forces.  At any rate, I also wasn't saying that one _could_ start with a perfectly-known $x$ -- I was trying to explain the meaning of a covariance matrix, in simple, if over-the-top, terms.

Comment: [Yeah](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1789/50076)